# How to use `tlmgr` to install all available babel language packages?

Tags: texlive, babel, tlmgr

I can install single additional language packages with

```
tlmgr install babel-german babel-french
```

for example.

However, how can I just install all available languages?

Comment: In case somebody is interested: if you have installed `texlive` with `apt` in Ubuntu (instead of `tlmgr`) then there are also a few language metapackages available, for example `texlive-lang-european`, `texlive-lang-other` (with some Asian languages), `texlive-lang-all`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the list with

```
tlmgr info --data name | grep 'babel-'
```

After that it's just a question of feeding the output to `tlmgr install`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a one-liner to install all packages beginning with `babel-`:

```
for package in $(tlmgr info --data name | grep '^babel-'); do tlmgr install "$package"; done
```

Comment: Just needed this again and leaving it here in case someone else needs it, too :)